# start docker container several ports

Tags: docker, ansible

I need to start a docker container with several port mapping as following:

```
- name: Run My container
  docker_container:
    name: "MyContainer"
    image: "MyImage"
    state: present
    pull: true
    restart_policy: always
    published_ports:
      - 1200:1200
      - 1201:1201
      - 1202:1202
      - 1203:1203
      .
      .
      .
      - 1300:1300
```

What I want to do is to run Ansible script as:

```
- name: Run My container
  docker_container:
    name: "MyContainer"
    image: "MyImage"
    state: present
    pull: true
    restart_policy: always
    published_ports:
      - 1200-1300:1200-1300
```

Although, It doesn't work, Ansible give me the following error message:

`File \"/tmp/ansible_8zDYC9/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", line 987, in _parse_publish_ports\r\n    container_port = int(parts[-1])\r\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1200-1300'`

Is possible to map several ports betwen host and container in the same line?

PS: I'm using Ansible 2.3

Comment: Any solution on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have the conclusion but u need to set the ports in double quotes like these:
"1200-1300:1200-1300"

Comment: were you able to find any solution on this ?